# offline web app fails to open after ios 7 upgrade

Tags: sqlite, ios7

I have a webapp that I created well over a year ago, and running on iOS 6, it's been rock solid. It's designed to work offline and online, from the same home screen icon. I've got a manifest file that loads up the bootstrap javascript, all the js includes, and the core files. The app is designed to store data while offline (using SQLite) then transfer anything in the offline queue to a MySQL database once online. And again, all this was working on iOS 6 with absolutely no changes whatsoever to any of the files, the manifest, etc. for months.

Then I upgraded to iOS 7.

Now I have a host of problems, but they all seem to revolve around database issues. I'm getting a lot of code 6 errors in Chrome (in Safari, I get nothing, just a blank screen). In my reading up on this I found that Apple did make some sort of change to how SQLite runs, but not being an xcode developer I don't have access to the materials on Apple's site, and since I'm not running xcode in any case I don't know if that even applies to my purely HTML app.

My question, then, is this: with whatever changes Apple made on the app side, is there anything that would have affected the functionality of a pure HTML5/JS/SQLite offline web app, bookmarked to the home page via Safari?

Answer (score 1):

IOS 7 limit browser DB size from 50MB to 5MB , is that the reason ? Also I met a end user turn on Private Browsing in their IPAD  , also could cause this trouble, hope that helps.
you can check this :http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

Comment: +1 for the information, though I don't think any of it applied to me. My db was set to 5mb (well, 5 * 1024 * 1024 bytes, though just to be sure I dropped it to 4). The app works as expected on my Nexus after a slight JS change, but still not on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I figgured it out.When you enter safari, a little button on the top left on the keyboard says "private", click it to disable it. The database will work fine. But! jquery mobile will not be able to use the back button. For this, you have to delete appcache from your code. jquerymobile 1.4 will fix this, but for now you will have to live without appcache!